# ReadOnly Property that Entity Framework can set

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Very basic, yet my Google-fu is failing me.

I have a domain object, say User, that I want the Active property to be read only on.  Yet, the property needs to be set via EF(6) when loaded from the database.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
    -- other stuff
);
```

Class:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }    // this should be RO

    public void Activate() {
        Active = true;
        this.AddChangelog(ChangeType.Activation, "Activated");
    }

    public void Deactivate() {
        Active = false;
        this.AddChangelog(ChangeType.Activation, "Deactivated");
    }

    // changelogging, etc.
}
```

Developers should not change `Active` directly, but instead should use the `Activate()` and `Deactivate()` methods.  Yet, EF6 needs set `Active` directly so it can instantiate the object.

**Architecture** (if it matters):

- User class exists in `Domain` project
- EF6 class configuration is done via `Data` project
- EF6 uses Fluent API configuration (keeps ORM stuff out of my domain project)
- EF6 does not use DTOs but configures the domain classes directly

**Question**

How can I enforce (or at least warn) devs not to set `user.Active`?  At very least, can I offer some compile-time warning (akin to `[Obsolete]`) to the setter so they get a notice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use friend assemblies to solve your problem and make it public to your project that you want and make it private to other projects.

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("cs_friend_assemblies_2")]
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)